# Architecture of Wizard type Image Processing App

Tags: java, image-processing, architecture, layer

We are building a wizard-style image processing software. It consists of three layers: GUI, Engine and Core_Algorithms.

**Wizard:** Each "panel" of the app asks the user to do something. Example: first panel asks the user to load some images, the next panel applies "seed region growing" (SRG) algorithm and asks the user to adjust the result by using "magic wand tool".

**What happens behind the scene:** All the algorithms are kept in the package "core" (and are completely independent of the GUI). All the data items (for the entire app) are stored in single class (**Data.java**).

**Data.java**

```
/*Stores ALL the necessary data items*/
public class Data{

    BufferedImage sourceImage, targetImage;
    BufferedImage srcGrownImg;
    Point srcPoint, tarPoint;//and many more data items for each algorithm and panel
}
```

Another class (**Engine.java**, which is extended from Data.java) uses those data items, runs appropriate algorithms (like SRG.java from "core" package) and stores the items (inside Data.java).
Each phase of wizard has the same instance of "Engine.java", so that they can set, run algorithms and get the results.

**Engine.java**

```
/*Runs algorithms inside "core"*/
public class Engine extends Data{
    public growSource()
    {
        SRG srgObj = new SRG(srcImg, srcSeeds);
        srcGrownImg = srgObj.runAndGetResult();
    }//and many more functions for each panel
}
```

**Problem:** The problem we are having is that "Data.java" and "Engine.java" are too long. Engine.java consists of functions which are short and sweet (3-4 lines) (but all the functions used by the entire wizard are stored inside it, thus making it really long).

**Question:** I want advice on how to break the code up, so that "Data.java" and "Engine.java" become shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to apply the [*adapter pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to evoke disparate implementations of a common interface, such as `runAndGetResult()`. The result is to have as many concrete implementations as there are ways to effect `runAndGetResult()`.

This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) illustrates he pattern for a single abstract function, `eval()`, but multiple interfaces may be implemented. A [class literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) is used as a runtime type token to obtain an implementation by name, but a registry is also possible.

In a GUI, the adapter might extend [`AbstractAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for use in buttons, menu items and other components that accept `Action`. For off-line processing, a list of adapters could be composed in the GUI and later evaluated in the prescribed order in another thread.